# can't access property "REACT_APP_SC_ATTR", process.env is undefined

Tags: next.js, styled-components

I recently uploaded my next.js version, and this error poped up. I didn't change anything
[image: This is what it says]

Anyone knows what's happening? I'm desperate.

Comment: How do you define and how do you access it? Please post the code, not screenshots

Comment: Please provide a [mre].